# Can't get video details even with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm trying to set up an app to do some background work for me on a website. Users submit a facebook video link and I'd like to use the Facebook SDK to get the video details such as description, etc.

I'm using Facebook Graph API to test my query. The documentation says I need no parameters even in the Graph API, just use /{video-id} and it should work. I tried, and I didn't manage to get it. I'm sure the video has a public privacy as well. What am I doing wrong?

I also added user_videos permissions to the access token but still nothing. I figure if I get it working in Graph I'll know how to use the PHP SDK as well.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The user that own the video have granted user_videos permission to your app?

Comment: No, they haven't. The video ID I'm using is a publicly visible ID that can be viewed even in an non-logged in environment outside facebook. I've no way of connecting the users to the video as I'm picking random videos from my own facebook news feed and trying to get the same information I see on my feed through the Graph API